# How do I visualize a non-unique least-squares solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Suppose $Nul(A)$ has dim $> 0$. This means there are infinite solutions to the normal equations $A^{T}A\hat{x} = A^{T}b$. That is, you can define $\hat{x}$ parametrically.

From what I understand about the least-squares solution $A\hat{x}$, it is the closest point from the $Col(A)$ to $b.$ But what does it look like when there are infinitely many closest points? I'm having a hard time trying to visualize it.

Comment: The part of $Col(A)$ closest to $b$ is only one point, but $A$ can send many points to it. The image $Ax$ can be already as close as it gets to $b$. As soon as you have some other point $y\neq x$ that is sent to the same place $Ay=Ax$. Then all the points $x+t(y-x)$ are also sent to the same spot $A(x+t(y-x))=Ax+tAy-tAx=Ax$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks :)